# How to run jest in multiple processes

Tags: jestjs

I want to run multiple test cases in separate processes. For this I created tests with the following structure:

```
it.concurrent.each(['case1', 'case2', ...], () => { ... });
```

This does not seem to create separate processes, only run asynchronously. In my actual tests I use `mock-fs` to not write to the filesystem. Mocking the filesystem breaks when running asynchronously within the same process. Therefore, I would like to run each test in a separate process. From the docs it seems that this is possible: [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--workerthreads) indicates, that by default new child processes are spawned, but it doesn't tell me how to achieve this.

Does anyone know how to run the same test for multiple inputs in separate processes?